# ¿Como validar un registro y luego asignarlo a una base de datos?

Tags: python, django

Creé una app en Django, y quisiera hacer lo siguiente:

Tengo un modelo `Auto` donde tengo los atributos:

- `Placa` - entero
- `Marca` - texto

Tengo un modelo `Taller` que tiene 2 atributos:

- `Placav` - entero
- `Mecánico` - texto

Además un formulario donde estoy guardando los datos del modelo `Taller` y quisiera validar sin tener que hacer una relación uno a uno que seria lo más fácil, si esa placa que ingreso en el formulario se encuentra registrada en la base de datos en el modelo `Auto`.

Más o menos así desde las vistas:

```
a=auto.objecto.all()
b=taller.objeto.all()
if request.POST['placav']=Auto.placa:
    taller.placav.save()
else:
    "por favor ingrese un 
      valor existente"
```

Comment: La verdad no entiendo con mucha claridad lo que quieres hacer, respecto al paso 1 y 2, actualiza tu pregunta explicando con mas detalle lo que quieres hacer :)

Comment: Julio Cesar ahora si puedes mirar de antemano gracias

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo podrías utilizar el método `values_list`:

```
if request.POST.get('placav') in Auto.objects.values_list('placa', flat=True):
    print('Ya existe esa placa')

else:
    print('Placa valida')
```

Si entra al `if`, es que ya existe la placa.

Es decir que ya existe dicha placa o numero, como valor del campo `placa` en las instancias del modelo `Auto`.

Y para mas información, sobre el método `values_list`, revisa la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

Espero haberte ayudado.